# How to Access Author Meta (get_the_author_meta) in wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write my own code for populating JSON-LD Schema code (I'd rather not rely on plugins for this).

For Wordpress posts, one of the key schema elements is author data.  So I use get_the_author_meta() function to access it.

This works perfectly fine when it fires in the wp_footer action, but comes up empty when firing in wp_head.

I've checked this in the astra theme as well as twentytwentyone theme.

I stole this code just for demonstration purposes, it's twitter OG card and not Schema but its effectively the same.  Forgive me but I can't remember what stackoverlow post I found it in.

In functions.php:

```
function my_twitter_cards() {
    if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
    $twitter_user = get_the_author_meta('nickname'); #This is the element that works in wp_footer but not in wp_head, all the other fields seem to work.
    $twitter_url = get_permalink();
    $twitter_title = get_the_title();
    $twitter_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $twittercard_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    $twittercard_thumb = $twittercard_image[0];
    if (!$twittercard_thumb) {
        $twittercard_thumb = 'https://www.example.com/default-image.png';
    }
    if ($twitter_user) {
        echo '<meta name="twitter:creator" value="@' . esc_attr($twitter_user) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    echo '<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary" />' . "\n";
    echo '<meta name="twitter:url" value="' . esc_url($twitter_url) . '" />' . "\n";
    echo '<meta name="twitter:title" value="' . esc_attr($twitter_title) . '" />' . "\n";
    echo '<meta name="twitter:description" value="' . esc_attr($twitter_excerpt) . '" />' . "\n";
    echo '<meta name="twitter:image" value="' . esc_url($twittercard_thumb) . '" />' . "\n";
    echo '<meta name="twitter:site" value="@mhthemes" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_twitter_cards');  #swap this out for wp_footer to see the difference.
```

My theory was that it couldn't access the loop when called in the header, but that doesn't explain why post-specific data is populating (i.e permalink, title, etc), and not the get_the_author_meta data.

Now I can go with it if I just populate the footer, in this application it would be OK, but some things need to be in the header, so I want to figure out why its not working as expected.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_author_meta()` accepts two optional parameters:

```
get_the_author_meta(string $field = '', int|false $user_id = false)
```

Where `$field` is the user field to retrieve (Default value is '')
and `$user_id` is the user ID (Default value is false)

When used within The Loop, the user ID need not be specified, it defaults to the current post author. A user ID must be specified if used outside The Loop.

You can get the current post author ID outside The Loop, and then use it to fetch the desired author field like this:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$post_author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $post_id);
$twitter_user = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $post_author_id);
```

On a side note, the above example uses global $post because you are already using it in your code, otherwise I would use `get_queried_object_id()` to get the post ID outside of The Loop:

`$post_id = get_queried_object_id();`

Comment: Appreciate the response.  I guess I'm still a little confused.  If wp_head is outside the loop, has the query for this post started?  Why would get_queried_object_id() not run into the same shortcomings as other functions that default to the current post?

Comment: First of all, did my answer work for you? I hope that it did :) As for why some functions work outside The Loop while others don't - this is quite a complex question - that will be hard to answer in the scope of a comment. In short some functions rely on Global Variables and/or Body Classes that only becomes available inside The Loop. In your case get_the_author_meta() relies on a global var named $authordata to get the current user ID. This var is only available inside The Loop and that's why it needs an extra parameter - $post_author_id - to work outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks again, and yes, it works.  I knew a fallback would be to explicitly call the $post variable/etc, but I'm not sure what best practice is here.  I guess it all comes down to when the $post object is queryable as well as accurate.  I've got more studying to do.  If you've got any reading recommendations off-hand, I'll take 'em.  Thanks again!